# Can we dynamically change wix bootstrapper bundle version on every bundle.exe click

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

Can we dynamically change wix bundle version?

The following is the bundle.wxs:

```
<?include ..\CompanySetup\Includes\Variables.wxi ?>

<Bundle Name="Company 9.9.9" Version="$(var.bundleVersion)" 
        UpgradeCode="42d813f6-d293-xxxx-xxxx-75b213b0ea44"
        Manufacturer="Company" DisableModify="yes"
        DisableRemove="yes" DisableRepair ="yes" 
        AboutUrl="http://wixtoolset.org" >
```

I am getting bundleVersion from msi variables.wxi preprocessor variables
now since I can't have a dynamic value in preprocessor variables.... I need a solution to increment bundle version on every click of bundle.exe.